# Increase jQuery slider handle clickable area

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

I am looking to increase the clickable area on the jQuery slider handle. I don't, however, want to increase the visual size of the element. I don't want a giant handle. I just want to capture the click to the left and right of the handle, say by 10 pixels, to make it easier to "grab" the handle. Any ideas? Would I have to attach transparent divs there?

Comment: Can we see a demo of what you've got so far?

Answer (score 2):

I had some success by using CSS [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to create a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
But I cannot claim that this is the most effective solution.

In the example below I created a pseudo-element that extends 2em past the handle on the left and right, increasing its "hit area".

I don't like its oddly-shaped "active state" border.

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  orientation: "vertical"
});
```

```css
div#slider {
  margin: 3em;
}
span.ui-slider-handle::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  left: -2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="slider"></div>
```